# SQL function count in SELECT clause (clarifications with percentage)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, percentage

I have one table like this:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    - employee_id - level - study_environment - work_environment -                     
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    --                         values...                        --
    --------------------------------------------------------------
```

my request is to find two values:

- the total number of employees (`employee_id` is the primary key).
- the percentage of employees whom are of `level` `junior` or `senior` (possible value for `level`: `NULL, apprentice, junior, senior`) AND whom studied and work in the SAME CHOSEN environment.

My actual query is:

```
SELECT count(employee_id) AS quantity, ((count(level = 'junior' OR level = 'senior') * 100) / count(employee_id)) AS percentage
FROM table 
WHERE study_environment = 'law'
AND work_environment = 'law'
```

It doesn't work as expected and I'm almost sure that the error is in the `SELECT` clause but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `OR tipo='senior'` - Typo?

Comment: It's a typo but only here, thank I edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using conditional aggregation with `sum` and `case`:

```
select count(*) overallcount,
      100 * sum(case when level in ('junior','senior') then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)
FROM table 
WHERE study_environment = 'law'
      AND work_environment = 'law'
```

The count of true or false is still 1, thus summing incorrectly.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6672b/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple conditions in a CASE .... WHEN statement to do the appropriate counting/calculating:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total,
    (100*SUM(CASE WHEN (level = 'junior' OR level = 'senior') 
             AND work = 'law' AND study = 'law'
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/count(*) AS percentage
FROM employee;
```

This is similar to the other answer, but calculates the total of the entire table (i.e. every employee is counted), rather than only counting those records that meet the conditions set in the WHERE clause, which is (I think) what you want.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5feb0/21

(NB: I shortened the column names for my convenience, but the intent should be clear.)

More generically, if you want work = study (but not necessarily 'law'):

```
SELECT count(*) AS total,
    (100*SUM(CASE WHEN (level = 'junior' OR level = 'senior') 
             AND work = study
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/count(*) AS percentage
FROM employee;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18960a/1 (with slightly different test data)